# Does brown sugar draw moisture from cimmamon buns which makes them dry out fast?

Tags: bread, brown-sugar

Since everyone knows that brown sugar hardens fast and it draws moisture from anything moist (bread for example), does the brown sugar in the cinnamon rolls filling make them dry out faster? Since i notice cinnamon rolls dry out fast compared to other baked goods and i wonder if it has anything with the brown sugar, and is there tips to keep the cinnamon buns fresh for longer time?

Comment: Welcome! When you write “other baked goods”, do you mean yeasted items or other sweet treats like pound cakes?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply, by "other baked goods" i mean yeasted items.